# getting and setting enums in java

Tags: java, enums

I can't seem to figure this out:
I want to have an attribute of a class to be settable and gettable as an enumeration. The attribute in question is an objects shape, which can be either CONCAVE, CONVEX, or UNDEFINED. So I thought an enum would be good to use:

```
    private enum Shape {CONCAVE, CONVEX, UNDEFINED}
```

this is my constructor:

```
Vertex()
{
    point = new int[] {0, 0};
    Shape shape = Shape.UNDEFINED;
}
```

and here is its setter:

```
 public void setShape(Shape shape)
{
   Shape = shape;
}
```

and the corresponding accessor:

```
public Shape getShape()
{
    return  Shape;
}
```

and here is the compiler errors:

> ./Vertex.java:27: cannot find symbol
>   symbol  : variable Shape
>   location: class Vertex
>           Shape = shape;
>           ^
>   ./Vertex.java:56: cannot find symbol
>   symbol  : variable Shape
>   location: class Vertex
>           return  Shape;
>                   ^

I've tried all sorts of syntactical combinations and this is the closest I've come to.
I also need to know how to properly pass the enumeration value via the setter method in the 'calling' class...

Comment: is `Shape` enumeration a part of `Vertex` class?

Comment: Yes it is (sorry missed your question, dodgy internet connection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're **missing an instance variable** for the shape. Also, when allowing the Shape to be read and set, the **enum type must be accessible** (public, or package protected):

```
public class Vertex {

    public static enum Shape {
        CONCAVE, CONVEX, UNDEFINED
    }

    private Shape shape; // the instance variable
    private int[] point;

    public Vertex () {
        point = new int[] {0, 0};
        shape = Shape.UNDEFINED;
    }

    public Shape getShape () {
        return shape;
    }

    public void setShape (Shape shape) {
        this.shape = shape;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter.   Do I need to also define the Shape enum in the calling class? At the moment I get: VertexTest.java:41: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable Shape
location: class VertexTest
   vertices[i].setShape(Shape.UNDEFINED);   when using this code:    vertices[i].setShape(Shape.UNDEFINED);

Comment: In the implementation above it's a static inner class named Vertex.Shape, so you pass values like this: myVertext.setShape(Vertext.Shape.CONCAVE). You could also make a static import for Vertext.Shape and use myVertext.setShape(CONCAVE), or create the Shape as standalone enum in its own .java file.

Comment: Thank you! This sort of information is so hard to find-- I've been trawling resources all evening, and now you have given me an erudite and concise explanation. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I don't quite understand what you have now, but I think you need:

```
public class Vertex {

    private enum Shape {CONCAVE, CONVEX, UNDEFINED}

    private Shape shape;

    private int[] point;

    public Vertex() {
        point = new int[] {0, 0};
        shape = Shape.UNDEFINED;
    }

    public Shape getShape() {
        return shape;
    }

    public void setShape(Shape shape) {
        this.shape = shape;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your getter and setter methods are wrong because you've made a typo: you are referencing enumeration instead of class fields. It should be:

```
public void setShape(Shape shape)
{
   this.shape = shape;
}

public Shape getShape()
{
    return shape;
}
```

`shape` should be a class field:

```
Shape shape;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Vertex {
private enum Shape {CONCAVE, CONVEX, UNDEFINED};
Shape shape;

Vertex(){
  this.shape = Shape.UNDEFINED;}

public void setShape(Shape shape){
  this.shape = shape;}

public Shape getShape(){
  return  this.shape;}
```

You have no variable for Shape. A variable would resolve errors.